# Creating new .NET 6 MAUI project

Tags: c#, maui, .net-6.0

I want to work with MAUI and therefore installed all the necessary stuff (partwise using maui-check).

As given in some tutorials, I now want to create a new Project using `dotnet new maui` from the command line.
But I only get an error message:

> No templates found matching:'maui'.
> To list installed templates, run 'dotnet new --list'.
> To search for the templates on NuGet.org, run 'dotnet new maui --search'.

So why can't I use this command?

Comment: Which .NET Preview are you using? Is the workload installed? What do you see if you use `dotnet workload list` ?

Comment: did you run the `maui-check` tool with the "dev" option?

Comment: 6.0.100-preview.5.21302.13

Result dotnet workload list:
Workload Id
------------------------------
maui
microsoft-android-sdk-full
microsoft-ios-sdk-full
microsoft-maccatalyst-sdk-full
microsoft-macos-sdk-full
microsoft-tvos-sdk-full

Comment: maui-check --dev lets me install .net 6.0.100-preview.6.21355.2, but dotnet new maui still doesn't work

Comment: Try running `dotnet new -i Microsoft.Maui.Templates` and then `dotnet new maui`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible you haven't installed the templates yet. When I did my first `maui-check`, it said it failed to install the workloads; but subsequent runs supposedly found them. My `dotnet new maui` would fail with:

```
PS D:\Development\Technologies\MAUI\test-project> dotnet new maui -n HelloMaui
No templates found matching: 'maui'.
To list installed templates, run 'dotnet new --list'.
To search for the templates on NuGet.org, run 'dotnet new maui --search'.
```

Then I ran: `dotnet new -i Microsoft.Maui.Templates`

```
The following template packages will be installed:
   Microsoft.Maui.Templates

Success: Microsoft.Maui.Templates::6.0.100-preview.6.1003 installed the following templates:
Template Name         Short Name   Language  Tags
--------------------  -----------  --------  ------------------------------------------------
.NET MAUI App         maui         [C#]      MAUI/Android/iOS/macOS/Mac Catalyst/WinUI
.NET MAUI Blazor App  maui-blazor  [C#]      MAUI/Android/iOS/macOS/Mac Catalyst/WinUI/Blazor
```

And after that I was able to run:

```
PS D:\Development\Technologies\MAUI\test-project> dotnet new maui
The template ".NET MAUI App" was created successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of NET MAUI it allows you to create it as normal: `dotnet install maui && dotnet install maui-android && dotnet install maui-ios`, or try updating.
In case it is the most recent stable version use the command: `dotnet workload restore`